# React - How to use higher-level useState in imported functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following code (with some parts of it cut out for the sake of brevity) is working:

```
function AddressInputList({
  isOpen,
  inputValue,
  highlightedIndex,
  getItemProps,
  getMenuProps
}: AutocompleteInputListProps) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<MarkerPoint[]>([])
  const api = 'XXXX'
  const fetchURL = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?key=${api}&q=${inputValue}&limit=5&pretty=1`

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (inputValue !== null && inputValue.length > 1) {
        try {
          const request = await axios.get(fetchURL)
          const items = request.data.results.map((res: any) => {
            return {
              lat: res.geometry.lat,
              lng: res.geometry.lng,
              address: res.formatted
            }
          })
          setItems(items)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [inputValue])

  return (/*Code cut out*/)
}
```

What I now would like to do is to refactor the code to make it more lean. So I will create a `utility.ts`-file in which I have the `fetchData`-function and I subsequently would like to import the `fetchData`-function into the initial `AddressInputList`-function:

**utility.ts:**

```
export async function fetchData(inputValue: string, fetchURL: string) {
  if (inputValue !== null && inputValue.length > 1) {
    try {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchURL)
      const items = request.data.results.map((res: any) => {
        return {
          lat: res.geometry.lat,
          lng: res.geometry.lng,
          address: res.formatted
        }
      })
      setItems(items)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem here is that I don't know how to make the useState-hook `setItems` available in `utility.ts`. I read somewhere that this could be done with `props` but I'm not sure how this would look like. A short example would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not make it a third parameter to the function, pass in the setter function explicitly as a callback?

Comment: You could move the useState hook to that fetch data function by converting that fetchData function to a custom hook

Comment: @jonrsharpe: How would I do that? Could you make a brief example? Sorry I'm fairly new to coding, but I'm steadily learning :)

Comment: Which part - adding a parameter to a function, passing a parameter when calling it, something else? You seem to successfully be doing those things now.

Comment: @konekoya thanks I'm gonna take a look into custom hooks!

Comment: There's already an answer by Taras Danyliuk. You can give it a look. Since it's a custom hook, you can also wrap the `useEffect` in that hook as well.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for my imprecision. I meant the part about passing a setter function explicitly as a callback.

Comment: @konekoya my bad, I didn't refresh the page. Thanks a bunch to you guys for your suggestions, I think Taras' answer helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a custom hook that would fetch data for you.
I wouldn't recommend to tie this hook to `inputValue` so much. Also that .map formatting does not feel universal too.

```
export function useFetchData(inputValue: string, fetchURL: string) {
  const [items,setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (inputValue !== null && inputValue.length > 1) {
        try {
          const request = await axios.get(fetchURL)
          const items = request.data.results.map((res: any) => {
            return {
              lat: res.geometry.lat,
              lng: res.geometry.lng,
              address: res.formatted
            }
          })
          setItems(items)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
        }
      }
    }
  }, [inputValue]);

  return items;
}
```

After that you can use this custom hook like so

```
const items = useFetchData(inputValue, "/api/<endpoint>);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just pass setItems as a callback function, as a parameter to your fetchData function.

```
fetchData(inputValue: string, fetchURL: string, setItems) {
    ...
}
```